# ruby selenium webdriver minitest::test .* not matching in assert_match

Tags: ruby, regex, selenium

I am having trouble getting my regular expression to match the following:

> Expected
>   /.*IPcal\nIPcc\nIPcm\nIPcontact\nIPescalate\nIPim\n.*IPpm\nIPradar.*/
>   to match
>   "Equens-Prod-IPmon01\nEquens-Prod-IPmon02\nEquens-Test-IPmon01\nEVRYONE-Prod-IPmon01\nEVRYONE-Prod-IPmon02\nIPcal\nIPcc\nIPcm\nIPcontact\nIPescalate\nIPim\nIPlocksmithV2\nIPmonUI\nIPpm\nIPradar\nIPradar
>   New Request".

Does the .* not match anything 0 or more times in ruby or do I need a modifier to allow it to match the new lines, thinking the 's' modifier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help.

I needed to add the 'm' modifier to my assert_match and then the regular expression started matching.

Here is the final product:

```
assert_match(/(?i).*IPcal.*IPcc.*IPcm.*IPcontact.*IPescalate.*IPim.*IPpm.*IPradar.*/m, subtabs.text)
```